# Making Flappy Bird but how do I implement the pipes generating offscreen then going across the screen and despawning

Tags: python, pygame

So I am a bit stuck on how to implement the pipes spawning offscreen and making them move across the screen so that they can collide the bird and then DE spawning off screen. Do I need to give the pipes acceleration or something else?

I am fairly new to code but I have some ides on how to do it but I don't really know how to implement it or how to make a pipes randomly generate.

```
#Floppy disk
import sys, pygame
from pygame import mixer
import time

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
FRAMERATE = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


mixer.music.load('africa-toto.wav')
mixer.music.play(1, 0.0, 3000)

size = width, height = 1000, 1000
speed = [2,2]
power = [0.1, 0.1]
white = 255, 255, 255
black = 0, 0, 0
blue = 0, 255, 200
green = 0, 200, 0
dy = 2
dx =2
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)



player1 = pygame.image.load("floppy1.jpg")
pygame.key.set_repeat(1,1)
player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, (500, 500,10, 10))
playerrect = player1.get_rect()

background_image = pygame.image.load("circuit.jpeg").convert()

def obstacles():
    obst1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (500, 600, 100, 450))
    obst2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (500, 0, 100, 450))
    obst3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (700, 0, 100, 400))
    obst4 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (700, 550, 100, 500))

obstacles()  


while True:
    clock.tick(FRAMERATE)
    print(dy)

    if dy > 0:
        dy *= 1.03
        if dy < 2:
            dy *= 1.03
    if dy < 0:
        dy *= 0.9
        if dy > -1.3:
            dy *= 0.95
    if dy < 0 and dy > -0.6:        #Deceleraiton point
        dy *= -1.2
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
##            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
##                speed[0] -= power[0]
##            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
##                speed[0] += power[0]
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                dy = -10

                #speed[1] -= power[1]
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                speed[1] += power[1]

    if playerrect.bottom > height:
        dy = -20
    if playerrect.top < 0:
        dy = 15
    playerrect = playerrect.move(0, dy)
    
    #screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(background_image, [0,0])
    screen.blit(player1, playerrect,  obstacles())
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: The pipes have been defined as obstacles in the function, but I don't really know how to go about making more pipes without having to manual code them and randomly select the pipes @Rabbid76

Answer (score 0):

for multiple things that do very similar things i would highly recommend the use of **classes**: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

```
# you don't need to declare those variables globally, it's only one of multiple ways.
# a cleaner way would be to declare those as class variables, you can check out the 
# documentation (linked above) for more information.

# random needs to be imported
spawn_timer = 0
movement_speed = 2
x_size = 50
gap_size = 300
pipes = []
# screen, width and height have already been declared

class Pipe:
    def __init__(self, x_pos=width):
        random_height = random.randint(0, height - gap_size)
        self.upper_rect = pygame.Rect(x_pos, 0, x_size, random_height)
        self.lower_rect = pygame.Rect(x_pos, random_heigt - gap_size,
        x_size, height - random_height - gap_size)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, self.upper_rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, self.lower_rect)

    def collide(self, rect):
        return self.lower_rect.colliderect(rect) or self.upper_rect.colliderect(rect)

    def update(self)
        self.upper_rect.move_ip(-movement_speed, 0)
        self.lower_rect.move_ip(-movement_speed, 0)

# in the main loop:
spawn_timer += 1
if spawn_timer >= 200:  # use different values for distance between pipes
    pipes.append(Pipe())
    spawn_timer = 0
for pipe in pipes:
    pipe.draw()
    pipe.update()
    if pipe.collide(playerrect):
        print('GAME OVER')  # reset the game
if pipes and pipes[0].upper_rect.right < 0:  # first pipe will be leftmost pipe.
    pipes.pop(0)
```

also i noticed that the falling was not feeling as clean.
for a more natural movement, i would recommend *adding* something to the `dy` value instead of *multiplying* it.

if you have any questions, please write a comment.

EDIT: fixed `list index out of range` bug.
EDIT: fixed `'module' object is not callable`

Comment: `spawn_timer = clock.get_time()` would make more sense since that wouldn't depend on the frame rate, so `if spawn_timer >= 200` would be true every 0.2 seconds. Just a bit more controlled I guess.

Comment: I took that and tried to implement it in my code and got this error:    if pipes[0].upper_rect.right < 0:  # first pipe will be leftmost pipe.
IndexError: list index out of range    @Kesslwovv

Comment: `move_ip` move the rectangle *in place*, meaning it will change the rectangle instead of returning a moved version of the rectangle (like `move`). Documentation: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip

Comment: @KGGamingFluff I updated the answer

Comment: Another error it ran but once I think the pipes started to generate off screen this occured: line 122, in <module>
    pipes.append(Pipe())      and then the error was: line 67, in __init__
    self.upper_rect = pygame.rect(x_pos, 0, x_size, random_height)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable @Kesslwovv

Comment: @KGGamingFluff thank you, these `pygame.rect` needed to be `pygame.Rect` (uppercase) It's easy to mix those up...

Comment: There are no more errors now which is great but for me the pipes do not move. Do you know why @Kesslwovv

Comment: I don't really know. make sure `movement_speed` is not overwritten by another variable (you can print it in `Pipe.update` to check if it's still 2.) you can try using `self.upper_rect.x -= movement_speed self.upper_rect.x -= movement_speed` instead of `self.upper_rect.move_ip(-movement_speed, 0) self.lower_rect.move_ip(-movement_speed, 0)`